# how do I edit a mis-spelled tag?

Tags: discussion

I inadvertantly added a '#' to the tag 'chinese-philosophy' when I was creating the tag; I don't see any immediate way to get rid of it; how do I do this?

Comment: I would think retagging the questions with the tag would handle it, though there are some more direct tools if we need to intervene that way

Comment: I went ahead and retagged that one post which seems to repair it from our perspective